# Homewreckers wanted! Please handle these home-use questions

Tags: discussion

## Summary

ServerFault has numerous home-use questions extending far back into its history. It would be great if we could handle them all and either explicitly close them as off-topic or edit out all reference to the equipment being in the home leaving a useful question behind.

This is not a long-term, perpetual project. Just one to clean up our purpose and get to a point where we can reasonable believe that most historical home-use questions are either sufficiently edited or are closed so that we can move forward knowing that we're consistent.

Place home-use questions in the "Unhandled Questions" queue below and then, as we have time and motivation we can edit them or cast a close vote and then move the question to the proper heading below. If a question is fine as it is, it can be moved to the "fine as it is" heading.

Yes, this could get messy, however I'll bear with this topic and see it through until its end.

I have created a separate, temporary room called "[Homewreckers](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2268/homewreckers)" where we can place questions to be voted for closure. I didn't want to clutter up the regular VTC room with old posts. I think perhaps it would be better if 5 community members voted to close these questions than a single mod decision. Or at least, to get several community members' opinions before a flag is raised.

## Some Searches

- [Search with "home" in title](https://serverfault.com/search?q=title:home&submit=search) (probably over-broad, but it's a start)

## Unhandled Questions

- [HP MediaSmart Server - can it run WISA? Windows IIS SQL Server ASP.Net](https://serverfault.com/questions/803/hp-mediasmart-server-can-it-run-wisa-windows-iis-sql-server-asp-net)
- [Is there a way to throttle download/upload speeds through a router?](https://serverfault.com/questions/7609/is-there-a-way-to-throttle-download-upload-speeds-through-a-router) (Ward
  voted to close, this seems intrinsically home-use)
- [VPN from a Remote Desktop Session](https://serverfault.com/questions/6791/vpn-from-a-remote-desktop-session)
- [OS X: Can't Resolve Windows Machine Names](https://serverfault.com/questions/13337/os-x-cant-resolve-windows-machine-names) (Ward: same as above)
- [How do I tell OS X's implementation of Bonjour/ZeroConf which network to use for mdns?](https://serverfault.com/questions/11313/how-do-i-tell-os-xs-implementation-of-bonjour-zeroconf-which-network-to-use-for)
- [Multiple AD sites in single Hyper-V host and physical network](https://serverfault.com/questions/2428/multiple-ad-sites-in-single-hyper-v-host-and-physical-network)
- [Home Proxy Server](http://Home%20proxy%20server)
- [File sharing on Windows Home Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/8076/file-sharing-on-windows-home-server)
- [RDP Client on Vista Home Basic](https://serverfault.com/questions/40840/rdp-client-on-vista-home-basic)
- [Is this a secure setup for a home-based server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/61680/is-this-a-secure-setup-for-a-home-based-server)
- [Where to start for a home web server](https://serverfault.com/questions/101687/where-to-start-for-a-home-web-server)
- [Website hosting from home - IIS6](https://serverfault.com/questions/108232/website-hosting-from-home-iis6)
- [Assigning a home DNS to be secondary only?](https://serverfault.com/questions/128278/assigning-a-home-dns-to-be-secondary-only)
- [Can't Ping - Wireless network of home](https://serverfault.com/questions/217338/cant-ping-wireless-network-of-home)
- [Home-grown SAN — topology ideas?](https://serverfault.com/questions/267513/home-grown-san-topology-ideas)
- [DNS Piority in home-use Routers](https://serverfault.com/questions/120202/dns-piority-in-home-use-routers)
- [Apache+Home Server and no page loading](https://serverfault.com/questions/253643/apachehome-server-and-no-page-loading)
- [Centos Web Server Backup to home](https://serverfault.com/questions/348177/centos-web-server-backup-to-home)

More to come! If you find your own home-use questions, flag them or bring them up here.

## Handled

- [Can someone tell me how to reliably backup over a network using TimeMachine, without a TimeCapsule?](https://serverfault.com/questions/861/can-someone-tell-me-how-to-reliably-backup-over-a-network-using-timemachine-wit) (valid if "home" is stripped out, though not Best Practices)
- [How do you share a hard drive between a Mac and a PC?](https://serverfault.com/questions/8463/how-do-you-share-a-hard-drive-between-a-mac-and-a-pc) (Edited, but also marked as OT - More a SuperUser topic, but too old to move)
- [What is a good 64 bit physically small server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1731/what-is-a-good-64-bit-physically-small-server)
- [How do you share a hard drive between a Mac and a PC?](https://serverfault.com/questions/8463/how-do-you-share-a-hard-drive-between-a-mac-and-a-pc)
- [Is there a GUI for DNS lookups](https://serverfault.com/questions/6393/is-there-a-gui-for-dns-lookups) (Ward doesn't think this one deserved to be on
  the list in the first place, the only reason it was home-use was that he said it
  was to test a server at home.  Take out about 6 words and it's a valid question.)

## Fine as They Are

- placeholder

## A Little Backstory

While flagging home-use questions recently, I believe I went overboard and chose to request closure for questions that could have been rewritten. I've rewritten a number of questions, but that tends to clutter up the home page if I do it during the evenings when I have time to dedicate to the cause.

Perhaps if we all pitch in and edit or VTC a few questions a day, we can knock out the scourge of home use questions on the site and bring the site into better focus.

Comment: Do you have a search or a data explorer query you are working from ?

Comment: @Iain I have a few. I'll share sometime soon. (slammed for time ATM)

Comment: Is an off-topic question ever really "too old to migrate"?

Comment: @Andrew I would say... yes?

Comment: @WesleyDavid Why did the Q about a GUI for DNS get moved to "Unhandled?"  If editing it to make it not a home-use question wasn't enough, what did you want?

Comment: @Ward Ewpz. I was sifting through and saw that question had 4 close votes and thought we wanted to close it rather than let it life. I moved it.

Comment: @WesleyDavid It'll be less confusing (to me, anyway) if this list deals strictly with "home use."  If something like that DNS question also needs to be dealt with because it's NARQ or NC, I see that as a separate issue, it's still "handled" in terms of getting rid of its home use character.

Comment: @Ward It seemed pretty homey to me when I first posted it, but yes, this thread is purely about home use. So let it be written, so let it be done.

Comment: Are we clasifying everyone using "Windows XP/Vista/7 as a server" as home users? E.G. http://serverfault.com/questions/353790/bind-server-port-to-local-ip-address

Comment: @sam In general I think so, but I have seen applications in use that *require* one of the desktop operating systems for at least one component of its service. I think it's back to context - playing around with a Desktop OS as a server; kill it. Using it because you're forced to; depends!

Answer (score 3):

I like lizards. Sometimes turtles.

Comment: How about editing the original post of mine and shuffling around the things you've edited, deleted, closed and etc. within that rather than down here... ?

Comment: But I like trains.